# Is it possible to define the density of the logistic map for $x<0$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Probability density functions (PDF's) have inherent connections to the field of
Dynamical Systems.

The motivation for this question can be found in: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/2006/notes/solutions-2.pdf  for the logistic map when $x∈[0,1]$.

My **question** is:

Is it possible to define the density of the logistic map for $x<0$ where the map convegres to $-∞$?

Comment: Yes. The density is 0 there.

Comment: @  Anthony Quas: How you get this!

Comment: What is your definition of "density"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by Anthony Quas, if you are looking for an invariant probability measure that is supported on the basin of attraction of infinity, then you will need to put a point mass at infinity and nowhere else. (This is clear because a compact set will enter any neighbourhood of infinity after a sufficiently large - finite - number of iterates.)